# Bitmap-images or SVG

Tags: image, unity, bitmap-graphics, gui

I'd like to create a GUI in my first Unity-game (2D). I want my GUI appear sharp in all resolutions (e.g. 1920x1200 or 3840x2160).

The problem I am facing now is that I don't know if I should save my bitmap-images of my GUI in the highest resolution (so that it scales down when my game is played with a lower resolution) or should I use SVGs instead.

This may be a stupid question but it's the first time that I create a GUI in Unity and I'm really struggling with this kind of problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of your suggestions is a solution for crisp 2D graphics at all resolutions. SVGs are great and infinitely scalable, but since you don't know where the pixel boundaries will lie in the final render, you can't get crisp edges at all resolutions. For example, say your GUI is a red box on a green background. If the edge between the red and the green falls in the middle of a pixel, and the SVG renderer does anti-aliasing, you'll get a row or column of half-red, half-green pixels, which will look like mush. If the renderer doesn't anti-alias, you instead get the edge in the wrong place, which might be fine for a single rectangle, but for a repeating pattern each instance of the pattern might come out a different width, which is just as noticeable.

Downscaling a bitmap to the display resolution is just as bad. Again, imagine your green-red edge is on a pixel boundary that will not be a pixel boundary in the downscaled bitmap. You're again going to get a row or column of pixels that are a mushy red-green mix. The lowest resolutions are the most important to have crisp edges, but they're going to be the worst-affected.

You can make either one of these techniques work somewhat, if you can accept a restriction: instead of handling *any* resolution, you're willing to handle a set of resolutions, ideally powers of two apart (e.g. icon sizes of 512x512, 256x256, 128x128, etc.) When you're designing your UI, draw a large bitmap (512x512) or a vector image, but use guides in your editor to show the minimum size (e.g. 64x64). Make sure all your important edges line up with those guides, but you can still use curves, gradients etc. That way, you know you won't get the blurry mush at low resolutions, but you can still get the benefit of smooth diagonals and curves at high resolutions. This is a quick way to design scalable UI.

Mobile OSes (which are designed for a range of screen dpis) use a similar technique, but with two differences. First, they "bucket" the screen's actual dpi to the nearest "standard" dpi. This means a UI might show slightly larger or smaller on different screens, but you know exactly how many pixels will be in each icon or widget. To make this work out, they don't limit the resolutions to powers of two, but have some intermediate ones as well.

Second, they let designers specify a different bitmap for each resolution. This means that you can make a higher-detail design for a higher-dpi screen, without it being too busy on a low-dpi screen. (For example, you can use a fine checkerboard or ruler pattern, and have it show up correctly at each resolution.) You could consider doing this too, but it makes designing and managing the bitmap assets a little more time-consuming.

If your buckets are powers of two apart, you can use mipmaps to store the images (instead of using the built-in mipmap generation), whether you're creating different images for each resolution or just downscaling. That way you avoid the runtime memory bandwidth cost of downscaling.

Comment: Wow! That's an answer.:) This helps a lot. Thank you so much my friend!:D